# Why doesn't coverity show CHECKED_RETURN in my program?

Tags: return, static-analysis, checked, coverity

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int test() {
  const char* s = getenv("CNU");
  if (s!=NULL)
    return 1;
  else
    return -1;
}

int main() {
  test();
  // some C code..
  return 0;
}
```

**Commands that I use for coverity analysis:**

```
cov-build --dir Cov.build gcc test.c
cov-analyze --dir Cov.build --aggressiveness-level high --enable-callgraph-metrics --all
```

**report:**

```
Analysis summary report:
------------------------
Files analyzed                 : 1
Total LoC input to cov-analyze : 10926
Functions analyzed             : 2
Paths analyzed                 : 6
Time taken by analysis         : 00:00:01
Defect occurrences found       : 0
```

About CHECKED_RETURN:
https://ondemand.coverity.com/reference/7.6.1/en/coverity

Answer (score 3):

The `CHECKED_RETURN` checker is a statistical checker - it looks for examples where the return value is checked, and if a statistically significant (configurable) threshold is reached, defects will be issued for locations where you fail to check the return value.

If you want it to always issue a defect whenever you fail to check the return value, then you need to add `__coverity_always_check_return__()`, as shown in the example in the documentation you linked:

```
int always_check_me(void) {
  __coverity_always_check_return__();
  return rand() % 2;
}

int main(int c, char **argv) {
  always_check_me();  #defect#checked_return
  // the statement above is a defect because the value is not checked
  cout << "Hello world" << endl;
}
```

For obvious reasons, you'll need to also create a function stub for this for the source to compile (also mentioned in the documentation). If you want to make the code live only for Coverity, you can guard it with `#if __COVERITY__`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CHECKED_RETURN is a statistical checker error. If you check the return value of test() in 10 places, then in 11th place if you miss to check the return value of test(), coverity will return CHECKED_RETURN error. Ans show the statistics on how many places it checked out of total usage.